Book where an Earth woman travels with human-like aliens to their planet, where all men are bald
I vaguely remember reading this as a child in the late 90s or early 2000s.
What I remember is that a woman either agrees to go or has to leave Earth under dire circumstances with an alien woman (these aliens look just like us, but are taller, stronger and are all beautiful).
The two women (earthling and alien) then travel to the alien's planet where the earthling learns they release cosmetics in the air, so that everyone is beautiful and fit, and the only condition they couldn't fix was baldness. So all men are either bald or shave their heads so they look the same, but their leader is allowed to have hair as an exception.
I also remember the alien woman losing her arm at some point, maybe during a conflict, and how she didn't scream in pain and didn't pass out, but stoutly acknowledged the pain and the fact that her arm was cut off.
Does anyone remember reading this book?

Is this Yargo (1979) by Jacqueline Susann...?

Yargo tells the story of Janet Cooper, a young woman from Avalon, New Jersey, who is abducted by aliens from the planet Yargo. During her interplanetary adventures with these intelligent but emotionless extraterrestrials, she falls in love with their leader.

A young American woman named Janet Cooper is pulled up into a spaceship by a beam of light and taken to the planet Yargo. There, she is greeted by a Yargonian woman named Sanau.

Through the open wall entered the most beautiful woman I had ever seen in my life.
She was dressed exactly like the Yargonian men. The same brilliant colors, knee pants, gold sandals, and silken waist. Her eyes were also emerald color and slightly oblique. But she had hair — masses of it — ebony black, and pulled back with a severity that would have been unflattering on most women. It was caught up high in Grecian style by a jeweled clasp which allowed it to flow down her back to her hips. Her skin was white and absolutely flawless. Her nose was straight, and her mouth full and exquisitely formed. I grudgingly conceded, after downright rude scrutiny, that all this beauty was without aid of any cosmetic.
My admiration was lifted to awe when she addressed me in perfect though slightly stilted English.
"My name is Sanau. I bid you welcome to our planet."

Yargonian men and woman are all extremely attractive and dress much the same, but the men are all bald, since those who don't suffer from hair loss shave their heads to prevent those who do from experiencing envy (one of the Seven Deadly Sins, which they have attempted to abolish on their planet).

"What about the men of this planet? Are they also free of all vanity?"
Of course they were. Sanau went on to explain that they too were spared the burden of physical competition. Some five hundred years back, the males began shaving their heads when they learned that the man who lost his hair sometimes felt a physical inferiority to his more fortunate brother who was blessed with a full crop of hair. And since feelings of inferiority are contributing factors to envy, lust, and gluttony, they found the complete elimination of hair for all males an excellent solution.

Sanau ends up getting her right arm torn off by an alien monster, but takes the injury in stride.

Then, after a brief pause, she spoke again, slowly, painfully. "And as for my arm, I shall indeed miss it, but I shall manage. I only wish I had lost it in an accomplishment for my leader and my planet. It is sad to have lost it in such a needless fashion."

The book is available to borrow from the Internet Archive and has been published with several different covers; here's one of them.

